# Is there any benefit in activating NAT loopback for basic video gaming? Does it help a PS4 use UPnP?

Tags: nat, loopback

I have a router that I can turn on and off NAT loopback. The router is just used for game playing and phones and normal everyday Internet browsing.

My question is this will there be any benefit to having NAT loopback enabled? Will it help with PS4 UPnP or does it even have anything to do with that type of stuff? I’ve Google it and can’t come up with a definite answer.

Answer (score 9):

#### Short Explanation

Pretty confident the answer is enabling [NAT loopback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback) will not help you in any way for your basic needs. NAT loopback just simplifies the way a LAN connection might access services you expose to the world on your WAN. But if you don’t know what that means or haven’t dealt with that stuff, you should be fine without NAT loopback.

#### Longer Explanation

The main benefit of [NAT loopback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback) is that it allows one to treat the router’s WAN address as if it were in a LAN. This is beneficial if you have a hostname connected to the IP address of your WAN or just if you want to be able to access services via your WAN address instead of dealing with the internal LAN address.

Meaning let’s say you have an ISP assigned address of `123.456.789.0`. Whenever you do anything on the Internet, that `123.456.789.0` is connected to your actions. That’s the way most of us use our Internet connections.

But let’s say in you are hosting a service on your LAN behind your router. Meaning you have some server doing something at address `192.168.1.10`. Well, if you wanted to access those services on your LAN right now you would connect to `192.168.1.10`. Okay, that’s simple enough. But what if you wanted someone to access that server via the WAN on `123.456.789.0`.

Well, to have `123.456.789.0` access the services via `192.168.1.10` one would typically just setup port forwarding. Like let’s say `123.456.789.0` is running a web server on port `80`, then you would set your router to port forward port `80` connections coming to `123.456.789.0` so they go to `192.168.1.10`.

But what does any of that have to do with NAT loopback?

Well, here is the conundrum of port forwarding: If you wanted to access the web server on `123.456.789.0` via your LAN, you couldn’t use that address. You would need to use `192.168.1.10`. Which in some cases might be confusing.

What NAT loopback does is it allows you to tell your router to be aware of any requests coming from inside the LAN to port `80` and route them correctly to `123.456.789.0`.

This might sound like a trivial difference, but it can allow you to simplify bookmarks and stored connections by not having to keep track of two IP addresses. Just enable NAT loopback and then go to `123.456.789.0` and you will always get the server on `192.168.1.10` without ever having to remember that internal IP address.

The other benefit is if you had a domain name or hostname that pointed to `123.456.789.0` for some reason, that domain name or hostname would always work since it would always point to `123.456.789.0`. No need to edit a `hosts` file to “hack” an entry to point to `192.168.1.10`; just let NAT loopback properly route `123.456.789.0` to `192.168.1.10`.

Which is all to say: For basic gaming use and simple Internet browsing, you will most likely never bump heads with a scenario in which you would need to enable NAT loopback.

A nice explanation on when NAT loopback can and should be used can be found [on this NAT loopback page on the OpenSimulator site](http://opensimulator.org/wiki/NAT_Loopback_Routers). In the case of OpenSimulator, if someone is hosting a public aspect of OpenSimulator on their home computer, NAT loopback makes it easier for that public service to be advertised to the world and easily accessible to the “hoster” on the LAN as well.